# Variable type (generic or not) changes attributes behavior

Tags: java, generics

Minimal reproduction:

```
public class Main {
    public static class TestGeneric<T> {
        Map<String, Integer> testMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public static class Test {
        Map<String, Integer> testMap = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public static class Irrelevant {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Not generic, no problem.
        Test t = new Test();
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = t.testMap.entrySet().iterator().next();

        // Generic, but variable type also include generic information.
        TestGeneric<Irrelevant> t2 = new TestGeneric<>();
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry2 = t2.testMap.entrySet().iterator().next();

        // Generic, but variable type doesnt keep this info.
        TestGeneric t3 = new TestGeneric<Irrelevant>();
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry3 = t3.testMap.entrySet().iterator().next();
    }
}
```

The last line does not compile because `Object cannot be converted to Entry<String, Integer>`.

The only difference seems to be the type of the "root" variable. `t3` is type `TestGeneric` while `t2` is `TestGeneric<Irrelevant>`.
I don't understand how the type of the variable can change the return type of a class attribute whose type does not change. In all case, `testMap` remains a `Map<String, Integer>` but its `entrySet()` changes return type.

I am probably misunderstanding something with regard to Java Generic, but what?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That last line doesn't compile, but not because you use the `Irrelevant` class, but because the variable `t3` is raw.

When using a raw type, all generics from the class, even unrelated generics such as the type parameter of the `testMap` variable, undergo type erasure, as if they were raw also.  This is due to backwards compatibility rules from when generics were introduced to Java in JDK 1.5.

Effectively this means that `testMap` is now just a raw `Map`, whose `Iterator` returns `Object`.  This causes the compilation error you've seen.  You can supply the type parameter for the `t3` variable and the compilation error will be removed.

```
TestGeneric<Irrelevant> t3 = new TestGeneric<>();
```